# (Swift) How can I get a Data representation of the documentPicker URL

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, multipart, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I use the didPickDocumentAt function to retrieve the url of the picked file in the DocumentPickerViewController. I have a multipart upload function that uses alamofire to upload files to the backend.

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
    print(url)
    uploadMultipartFile()
}
```

My question is: How can I get a data representation of the file I have picked so I can pass it to my uploadMultipartFile function?

The Files can be pdf, .docx, or any kind of file. What is the approach?

Comment: Just use `Data(contentsOf: URL)` method and/or move/copy your file url

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at [`dataWithContentsOfURL:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1547245-datawithcontentsofurl)

> Returns a data object containing the data from the location specified by a given URL.

Note that it `throws` if it cannot create the data representation from the URL.

So in your case maybe something like this:

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, 
      didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
print(url)
    do {
        var documentData = [Data]()
        for url in urls {
            documentData.append(try Data(contentsOf: url))
        }

        //hopefully you have an array of data elements now :)                
        uploadMultipartFile()
    } catch {
        print("no data")
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: url is not optional and btw single url method is deprecated. you should use `documentPicker(_:didPickDocumentsAt:)` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerdelegate/2902364-documentpicker

Comment: @LeoDabus Sorry, you're right (it was in my playground example, thats why :)) Thanks for the catch, I've fixed it now.

Comment: Thank you so far but one more question, I remember having read about the files being sandboxed and that it is needed to do more to access them. Is that still true?

Comment: I’m actually not sure to be honest. I mean...your files are sandboxed yes, but that should allow you to access them. Also, if you look here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentPickerProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html there is a section about “Accessing Files Outside Your Sandbox” so that seems possible as well...just takes a little work. Sorry for the vague reply.

Answer (score 2):

For me it didn't work. What worked:

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
    guard
        let url = urls.first,
        url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
    else {
            return
    }
    defer { url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource() }
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        print(data)
        //DO SMTH WITH YOUR DATA
    } catch {
            print(error)
    }
}
```

Apparently that's due to security restrictions you need to have security bookmark to access file.